# google Local home local SDK Device Discovery

Tags: google-smart-home

Is there any Local Home SDK Sample that support BT BLE for Device Discovery?
I know there has a SDK that support Device Discovery UDP, mDNS, or UPnP.
I can not find the SDK can supprot BT BLE for DeviceDiscovery

Does anyone have idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[Seamless setup](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/seamless-setup?hl=en) is the feature you're looking for. Once you enable this capability in the console for your Action, you will be able to set BLE as the scan configuration. The [BleScanData reference page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/local/interfaces/smarthome.intentflow.blescandata?hl=en) should also help you get started.